# How to exclude a GET variable and rewrite as a redirect url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect `test.com/folder/create` to `test.com/folder/create(.php)`
but anything after `/folder/` is perceived as a `$_GET[]` variable with the lines below

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/index\.php$ [NC] 
 RewriteRule ^folder/([^/]*)$ /folder/index.php?type=$1
```

Ive tried

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/create\.php$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^folder/create$ /folder/create.php
```

But no luck (**Error 500**), can anyone point me in the right direction on how i could possibly do this?

**EDIT:** Still trying to search the web for an answer, no luck

**EDIT:** Small edit, 
Current Code

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^item\.php$ 

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?type=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?type=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^item/([^/]+)/?$ item.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^item/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ item.php?id=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

The rewrite base is /folder/
/folder/item works and redirect to item.php
/folder/item/2 gives a 500 Error, any suggestions?

Comment: just guessing a little, the 2nd one with out the rewrite condition, just the rule?

Comment: @rtfm nope don't work

Comment: You are missing the `/` in your RewriteRule.  Try `RewriteRule ^/folder/create$ /folder/create.php`.  Cause `^folder` means starts with folder, but it starts with `/folder`.

Comment: mod rewrite seems to work differently on every server i run, i just try an infinite number of things until i get lucky

Comment: @Nic3500 tried that just now, didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules in your `folder/.htaccess` (not in site root .htaccess):

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/

# append .php extension to every request that has a corresponding .php file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# rewrite all non-existing files and folders to index,php?type=...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .+ index.php?type=$0 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: How would i be able to do something like this `RewriteRule .+ index.php?type=$0&page=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: Normal - `/folder/index.php?type=$1` | With page `/folder/index.php?type=$1&page=$2` so something like`test.com/folder/type/page`

Comment: Just one final question, the lines `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]` allow me to go to `/folder/item` but ive added a rewrite cond to try allow me to go to `folder/item/x` but i keep getting 500 error any thoughts?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166116/discussion-between-richard-and-anubhava).

Comment: Okay do you know what the problem is? `/folder/item(.php)` work but `/folder/item/test` doesnt @anubhava

Comment: same on the chat page

Answer (score 1):

Try only with:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteRule ^folder/create$ folder/create.php
```